# While doing a question at GFG, I am getting this Runtime error in string Palindrome questions, "Time Limit Exceeded Your program took more time

Tags: c++, recursion, runtime-error

> *Test Cases Passed:  10000 /  10100
>
> Time Limit Exceeded
>
> Your program
>
> took more time than expected.Time Limit Exceeded Expected Time Limit
> 3.4sec Hint : Please optimize your code and submit again.*

Please Help me where I can Optimize my code? and this is the code.

```
// { Driver Code Starts
 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


 // } Driver Code Ends
//User function template for C++
class Solution
{
    public:
    int helper(string s, int start, int end){
        
        if(start>=end)
        {                     //base cond.
            return 1;
        }
        if(s[start]!=s[end])
        {                     //small work
            return 0;
        }
        
        return helper(s, start+1,end-1);  
        
    }
    
int isPalindrome(string S)
{
    int n=S.size()-1;
    return helper(S, 0, n);
    }
};
// { Driver Code Starts.

int main() 
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);
   
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;

        Solution ob;

        cout << ob.isPalindrome(s) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}  // } Driver Code Ends
```

Comment: I would try to replace the recursive function with an iterative one...

Comment: The least thing you could do: pass the `string s` as `const string& s`. @SergeBallesta With g++, I see a chance that the compiler turns this into an iteration by tail-call optimization.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple "optimization" which can / should be done in OPs code:

There is no need to pass the `string s` by value. It's not modified and can be given instead as const reference i.e. `const string& s`.

This is a simple lesson but the actual reason for writing this answer is the interesting observation I made in Compiler Explorer while fiddling with this example:

I compared the generated code for

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int helper(string s, int start, int end)
{
  if (start >= end) return 1; // base cond.
  if (s[start] !=s [end]) return 0; // small work
  return helper(s, start + 1,end - 1);
}
```

vs.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int helper(const string& s, int start, int end)
{
  if (start >= end) return 1; // base cond.
  if (s[start] !=s [end]) return 0; // small work
  return helper(s, start + 1,end - 1);
}
```

It's obvious that the only change I made is the recommended adjustment concerning the type of the `s` parameter.

I don't provide the full generated code but would like to emphasize the fact that the former version contains a recursive call

```
        call    helper(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)
```

while the latter does not.

[Full code on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vrsesazE6):

[image: Snapshot of Compiler Explorer]

From this I conclude that turning `string s` into `const string& s` somehow encouraged g++ to apply [tail-call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). I.e. it results in an iterative solution out of the rather simple-straightforward recursive source code of OP. (Not to mention that it reduced the emitted code to less than the half.)

Needless to say, that I expect a much better performance for the latter version — leaving the proof to OP.